# MediaBrowserServiceCompat unable to bind to service

Tags: android, android-studio, android-service-binding

My code is very simple, i just want to bind to the music service using MediaBrowserServiceCompat, actually i have a bigger program with the same problem so i tried to make a smaller one without all the unimportant parts and i get the following error:

> 08-27 11:31:30.848 12214-12214/com.example.android.newcheck E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                 Process: com.example.android.newcheck, PID: 12214
>                                                                                 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to bind to service com.example.android.newcheck.MusicStreamService@8c043ff with Intent { act=android.media.browse.MediaBrowserService cmp=com.example.android.newcheck/.MusicStreamService }: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'android.os.IBinder android.support.v4.media.MediaBrowserServiceCompat$MediaBrowserServiceImpl.onBind(android.content.Intent)' on a null object reference
>                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindService(ActivityThread.java:3847)
>                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:221)
>                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1887)
>                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
>                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7224)
>                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
>                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
>                                                                                  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'android.os.IBinder android.support.v4.media.MediaBrowserServiceCompat$MediaBrowserServiceImpl.onBind(android.content.Intent)' on a null object reference
>                                                                                     at android.support.v4.media.MediaBrowserServiceCompat.onBind(MediaBrowserServiceCompat.java:613)
>                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindService(ActivityThread.java:3834)
>                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:221) 
>                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1887) 
>                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158) 
>                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7224) 
>                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
>                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)

i mainly used Ian Lake lectures on youtube and did everything he said but i don't know why i get this error, i try to find answers online but couldn't find any answer. 
thanks for the help.

AndroidManifest:

```
    <service
        android:name=".MusicStreamService"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.media.browse.MediaBrowserService" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

MainActivity:

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    MediaBrowserCompat mediaBrowser = new MediaBrowserCompat(MainActivity.this, new ComponentName(MainActivity.this, MusicStreamService.class),
            new MediaBrowserCompat.ConnectionCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onConnected() {
                    Log.v("MainActivity","connected");
                }
                @Override
                public void onConnectionSuspended() {
                    super.onConnectionSuspended();
                }
                @Override
                public void onConnectionFailed() {
                    super.onConnectionFailed();
                }
            }, null);
    mediaBrowser.connect();
    Button click = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    click.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startService(new Intent(MainActivity.this, MusicStreamService.class));
        }
    });
}
```

MusicStreamService:

```
public class MusicStreamService extends MediaBrowserServiceCompat {
@Nullable
@Override
public BrowserRoot onGetRoot(@NonNull String clientPackageName, int clientUid, @Nullable Bundle rootHints) {
    Log.v("***********", "getroot");
    return new BrowserRoot(getString(R.string.app_name), // Name visible in Android Auto
            null); // Bundle of optional extras
}

@Override
public void onLoadChildren(@NonNull String parentId, @NonNull Result<List<MediaBrowserCompat.MediaItem>> result) {
    Log.v("*********", "one step before connect2");
    result.sendResult(null);
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    MediaSessionCompat mediaSession = new MediaSessionCompat(this, MusicStreamService.class.getSimpleName());
    setSessionToken(mediaSession.getSessionToken());
    mediaSession.setFlags(MediaSessionCompat.FLAG_HANDLES_MEDIA_BUTTONS |
            MediaSessionCompat.FLAG_HANDLES_TRANSPORT_CONTROLS);
    mediaSession.setActive(true);
}
```

Comment: https://medium.com/google-developers/mediabrowserservicecompat-and-the-modern-media-playback-app-7959a5196d90#.ck07s5vqc, in this tutorial he didn't speak about bindService call. Anyway, if I use bindService call i get an error in queryLocalInterface, but when I use bindService calls with service without the mediaBrowserServiceCompat everything's working fine.

Comment: is it a good idea to use Binder in MediaBrowserServiceCompat?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I forgot to write super.onCreate() in the onCreate method in MusicStreamService class. solved.

Comment: In my case, I had an issue with *public IBinder onBind(Intent intent)* function in the service class. It should not return null. I just removed the override of the function and it solved the issue.