# Communication problems between fragment and a server

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-service, mediabrowserservicecompat

I have a fragmment that I would like to communicate with a server, but the problems is that i always get null pointer

I have this in my fragment onCreateView:

```
public class BrowseFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener{

private MusicService mMusicService;


@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, container, false);



    mMusicService = new MusicService(this);
             mMusicService.setCallback(new MusicService.Callback() {


                                @Override
                                public void onPlayPause(String state) {
                                    //Do something
                                }
                            });

}
}
```

This is my service:

```
 public class MusicService extends MediaBrowserServiceCompat {


public interface Callback {
        public void onPlayPause(String state);
    }

    public void setCallback(Callback callback) {
        this.mCallback = callback;
    }





private void PauseRequest() {
        mPlayback.pause();
        //if (mCallback != null) {
            mCallback.onPlayPause("PAUSE");
        //}
}

}
```

I´m getting this FATAL EXCEPTION: main

```
Process: com.geobytenet.mediaplayer, PID: 3262
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void com.example.android.mediabrowserservice.MusicService$Callback.onPlayPause(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
```

I hope you can help me

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39179317/mediabrowserservicecompat-unable-to-bind-to-service

Comment: Maybe i wans't clear. The server is working what is not working is the interface and im getting an error in mCallback.onPlayPause("PAUSE");

Comment: Is your fragment being displayed when you try to use the interface?  If it no longer has focus, there's a chance your fragment is being destroyed before you call the implementation.  Are you sure that `mCallback` doesn't get altered elsewhere in the Service?  I've put together something similar & this works for me.

Comment: Yes my fragment is being displayed, the app is working fine, but i get the error when i click on the button that do the CallBack. Can you share the code you said your working to see if it helps me?

Comment: Mostly, I just copied the code you posted.  Since you didn't post how you call `PauseRequest()`, I wasn't sure how it was called.  I created a public method in the Service & call `PauseRequest()` from it.  Then in the fragment, I created a button & in `onClick()`, I call the public method in the Service  `mMusicService.pausePlay();`  If the formatting due to this being in a comment makes it unreadable, I can post an answer if you need.

Comment: Sure please do that so I can accept your answerd, Thank you

Comment: I just posted the info as an answer.  Sorry for the delay.  I had this marked as a Favorite but SO never notified me of your comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MusicService, I added this method

```
    public void pausePlay() {
        PauseRequest();
    }
```

Then in BrowseFragment, in `onCreateView()`

```
    Button button = (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.button_play_pause);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            mMusicService.pausePlay();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not create MusicService in Android like simple class. It is a service and it must be started in a right way https://medium.com/google-developers/mediabrowserservicecompat-and-the-modern-media-playback-app-7959a5196d90

Comment: Maybe i wans't clear. The server is working what is not working is the interface and im getting an error in mCallback.onPlayPause("PAUSE");